# How can I display an Image from MS SQL Server on to a MS Access form?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

Recently I was up scaling from MS Access to SQL Server (back end).

Everything up sized smoothly using the wizard. I only have one problem, when trying to access the pictures that were stored in SQL Server in MS Access (Front End).

Before up scaling to SQL Server, I had the image stored as an attachment on MS Access which caused a problem as SQL Server does not support multivalued columns and it was converting the data type to `ntext` (in the up scaling process). Then I tackled this problem by storing all the multi valued (picture/attachment) in a table on it's own and referring to the owner by a fk. The newly created table have these properties ID_number PK *text*, FileData *OLE OBJECT*, FileName *text*, FileType *text*

All of these correspond to the table `dbo.IMAGE` on SQL Server linked with MS Access with and ODBC connection. The properties found in this tables are :

```
ID_number nvarchar, FileData Image, 
FileName nvarchar, FileType nvarchar
```

Is there anyway to get the image to display on a MS access form as I'm having trouble loading the image from SQL Server. I did some research and found out that I have to use `GetChunk` And `AppendChunk` methods but I don't no where to start.

Comment: Start with picking the **most appropriate** datatype! `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, although I already read this article, I had some problems to change the mapping values from MS access to SQL Server but I could change Image to varbinary(max) but I have no idea how to display a varbinary(max) into an image control source (Access). I'm already using nvarchar(max) on MS Sql Server which is connected to Access (Front end)